# ECMA CLI spec: stack transition diagram notation for CIL instructions

Tags: stack, specifications, cil, intermediate-language

I have been reading the ECMA CLI spec:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

and I'm puzzled by the use of commas within the stack transition diagrams for some of the instructions. For example, here is the documented stack transition for `ldloc` (load argument onto the stack):

`… => …, value`

And here is the stack transition for `ldsfld` (load static field of a class):

`…, => …, value`

My question has to do with the extra comma before the instruction: Does it have any significance? Another example is `jmp` (jump to method):

`… => …`

and `br.<length>` (unconditional branch):

`…, => …`

There are also examples of trailing commas such as for `nop` and `starg.<length>`. Is this just an inconsistency or is there a nuance to this notation that I don't understand?

Comment: It's safe to say this holds no significance. The online docs for the individual opcodes for [`jmp`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.jmp) and [`br.S`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.br_s) both use the much more explicit description "no evaluation stack behaviors are performed by this operation". (`ldloc` and `ldsfld` likewise both state, in words, that a single value is pushed onto the stack.) Fortunately the commas appear to be superfluous rather than [blasphemous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_errata#King_James).

Answer (score 0):

The commas are simply there to show you that the rest of the evaluation stack doesn't change. The stack could have values before (it's very common to put stuff on the stack and do other operations while they're there).
If you see `… => …` - this instruction doesn't change the stack at all.
If you see `… => …, value` - this instruction adds one value to the stack
If you see `…, value => …` - this instruction removes one value from the stack

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Basically my question is what's the difference between `… => …` and `…, => …`

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that. I can only assume that this is a mistake in the document. They absolutely have no meaning.